# Cannot assign a void to an implicitly-typed local variable using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, linq-to-entities

I am using a **WCF refrence** to call the last row from my `Quote` table. Now I wrote this method in my WCF application to get the last row, but I do not know it it works or not(I am trying to test it):

```
public void GetLastQuote()
{
    using (TruckDb db = new TruckDb())
    {
        var quote = (from qData in db.Quotes
                     where qData.Id == qData.RepresetativeId
                     orderby qData.Id descending
                     select qData).First();
    }
}
```

In my WPF application I am using the WCF reference and calling on the `GetLastQuoteAsync()` method, but it is giving me the following error:

> Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable

And here is the method in my WPF application where I am trying to call the `GetLastQuoteAsync()` reference.

```
private async void wListOfBills_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (TruckServiceClient client = new TruckServiceClient())
    {
        var quote = await client.GetLastQuoteAsync(); // -> This is where the error lies.
        var bills = await client.GetListOfBillsAsync(quote.Item.Id);
        if (bills == null)
        {
            dgFloor.IsEnabled = true;
            return;
        }
        dgFloor.ItemsSource = bills.Select(x => new ListOfBillsView
        {
            Code = x.StockCode,
            Group = x.GroupName,
            Description = x.StockDescription,
            Qty = x.Quantity,
            Length = x.Length,
            Width = x.Width,
            Weight = x.Weight,
            Price_m = x.PricePerMeter,
            Cost = x.Cost,
            Section = x.TruckSection.ToString()
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

I have seen some people with the same question, but I do not fully understand how to implement the solutions in my own problem. If anyone could help, I would appreciate it allot! :)

Comment: its clear that GetLastQuoteAsync returns nothing to be assigned to quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to call what your query is returning, but the method wrapping around that query is returning nothing, because its type is void.

I assume you want to return an object of type `Quote`, so you need to change your method to this:

```
//change from void to Quote
public Quote GetLastQuote()
{
    using (TruckDb db = new TruckDb())
    {
        var quote = (from qData in db.Quotes
                     where qData.Id == qData.RepresetativeId
                     orderby qData.Id descending
                     select qData).First();
        //new
        return quote;
    }
}
```

Also `GetLastQuote()` is not the same as `GetLastQuoteAsync()` Have you posted the wrong method, which would throw the same error?

If there is also async version of this method it should probably look similar to this:

```
public async Task<Quote> GetLastQuote()
{
    using (TruckDb db = new TruckDb())
    {
        var quote = (from qData in db.Quotes
                     where qData.Id == qData.RepresetativeId
                     orderby qData.Id descending
                     select qData).FirstAsync(); /*Note async method here*/
        //new
        return await quote;
    }
}
```

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Yes I noticed that too, after seeing that those 2 methods have different names. I extended my answer to cover any of those 2 cases.

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thank you for your time and effort :). I also fixed the `GetLastQuote()` with `GetLastQuoteAsync()`. I forgot to add the **Async** when asking the question.